# Retrieving Notes data using time machine on external hard drive to a new laptop

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, backup, time-machine, notes.app

I'd like some help pleases.  I have a time machine backup of my old macbook air (purchased 2013) which is no longer operational.  I have a new macbook air purchased 2022 and I would like to transfer the data stored on the time machine from the old laptop to my Notes app on my new laptop please.  I have looked online but cannot work it out.

FYI The external hard drive that was the time machine back up for the old laptop is not the time machine backup I use for the new laptop.

TIA